# DateTimePicker control with a custom format, how to set the time value?

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, type-conversion, datetimepicker

I have a `DateTimePicker` control called '`dtpickStartTime`' , it has a custom format of 'HH mm' (`dtpickStartTime.CustomFormat = "HH mm"`). I use it to select a time which works fine (I get times from it fine, in that format). However, I am struggling to set the time.

I am setting the time from an array of controls that have labels on them `PanelField(i).lblStartTime.Text`, bit complicated but all this means is the value Im trying to set is '00 00' or similar, which is in that custom format

But it doesnt seem to work

```
JobAddingForm.dtpickStartTime.Value = CDate(PanelField(i).lblStartTime.Text)
```

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "14 20" to type 'Date' is not valid.'

Does anyone know how to set the time programmatically? 
I have tried to do

```
JobAddingForm.dtpickStartTime.Value = New DateTime(0, 0, 0, PanelField(i).lblStartTime.Text, 0, 0)
```

But to do that you need to have it as `(0, 0, 0, 14, 20, 0)`
and the label contains the value of '14 20' so it looks as `(0, 0, 0, 14 20, 0, 0)`

I also wasnt sure what to search for to solve this problem so I am asking this question, I hope Ive explained it well enough and if anymore information needs to be provided I can do that. Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert a "non-standard" string to a DateTime, instead of `CDate` you should use [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) or [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx), both of them can get a parameter specifiying the format of the input string. In your case,this should work:

```
JobAddingForm.dtpickStartTime.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(PanelField(i).lblStartTime.Text, "HH mm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! :D I cannot rate it as useful because of my low reputation but I will mark it as an answer as soon as possible :)